# Why isnt my images showing in python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so when I was trying o make a game the front page is good

[Front page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IahI7.png)

but when I tried the game no image is shown. why? how can it get to fix it without changing the system order?
it always shows no image or just nothing in my other projects don't know why

[a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Dn9.png)

here code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from Winsound import *

win = Tk()
win.config(bg="#e300ff")
win.geometry("950x600+160+60")
win.resizable(width = False, height = False)


def play_sound_play():
    global playgame
    PlaySound("SoundEffects\Coins.wav", SND_FILENAME)
    playbtn.destroy()
    win.config(bg="white")
    playgame = True
    game()

def printpos(event):
    print(f"{plr_posx}")

def MoveLeft(event):
    global plr_posx
    if plr_posx == 311:
       print("cant go into grass")
    else:
       plr_posx -= 150
       plr.place(x=plr_posx,y=plr_posy)
    
def MoveRight(event):
    global plr_posx
    if plr_posx >= 610:
       print("cant go into grass")
    else:
       plr_posx += 150
       plr.place(x=plr_posx,y=plr_posy)

def game():

    global plr
    global plr_posx
    global plr_posy

    #road
    road_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("texture\ymd.png"))
    road = Label(win, image=road_img)
    road.pack()
    road.place(x=321,y=0)

    #grass
    grass_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("texture\grass.png"))
    grass1 = Label(win, image=grass_img)
    grass1.pack()
    grass1.place(x=-2,y=0)
    grass2 = Label(win, image=grass_img)
    grass2.pack()
    grass2.place(x=646,y=0)

    #Plr pos
    plr_posx=311
    plr_posy=450

    #Plr
    plr_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("texture\Player.png"))
    plr = Label(win, image=plr_img)
    plr.pack()
    plr.place(x=plr_posx,y=plr_posy)

    if playgame == False:
       print("2")
    else:
       print("1")
       #controls
       win.bind("<Left>",MoveLeft)
       win.bind("<Right>",MoveRight)
       win.bind("<p>",printpos)

def main():
    global playbtn

    #PlayBtn
    play_btn = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("texture\play_btn.png"))
    playbtn = Button(win, image=play_btn,bd=0,bg="#e300ff",activebackground='#e300ff', command=play_sound_play)
    playbtn.pack()
    playbtn.place(x=150,y=250)
    win.mainloop()

main()
```

no error is shown

[No Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZm3o.png)

even after I close it
[no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YGla.png)

Comment: You set it to white background and then ... do nothing: You call `game()` which doesn't do anything (except declares those variables as global) or You have not formatted the code correctly in the question

Comment: you see if I did that it will not show the grass, road, pls, in game() and it will show the only color if I did bg color.

Comment: Ok, I will ask You again, take a look at the code You have posted, if it is correctly formatted and `game()` is defined as shown in the post, then I can tell You that it does absolutely nothing, ok so it would be great if You properly formatted the code with the correct indentation

Comment: also why are You `.pack()`ing and then immediately `.place()`ing widgets? there is no point just use `.place()` or just `.pack()` not both

Comment: I edited the code. and I use ".place()" because in "play_sound_play()" i do or ".destroy()" or "forget_pack()" and i do "forget_pack()" and do "pack()" agein it will not save the pos.